# how to send xml parameter to WCF?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

How to send xml parameter to call `WCF` method? My client side code is in `AJAX,JSON` using jQuery.I want to pass xml value as parameter.How to pass xml value?
My xml value is

```
<value><Root>mydata</Root></value>
```

My client side code--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

          jQuery.support.cors = true;

            var bhRequest = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                "<s:Body>" +
                "<GetSMC xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
                  "<value><Root>MyValue</Root></value>" +
                "</GetSMC>" +
                "</s:Body>" +
            "</s:Envelope>";

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnWCFBasicHttp").click(function () {
                    alert("hi");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:8130/MyService.svc/bh/",
                        data: bhRequest,
                        timeout: 10000,
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/GetSMC");

                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("success");
                            $(data).find("GetSMCResponse").each(function () {

                               document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = $(this).find("GetSMCResult").text();
                                                         });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(error);

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <input id="btnWCFREST" type="button" value="Call WCF using JQuery" />
         <label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></label>

        </div>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it'll work, but try to put that XML inside
`<![CDATA[` and `]]>`

There is also some hack with string tag, but I don't know if it is necessary (maybe only CDATA tag will be enough):
[WCF RESTFul service - Pass XML as string to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702915/wcf-restful-service-pass-xml-as-string-to-service)

Comment: What happens? Without XML it works? What is a type of that parameter?

Comment: I am passing string as parameter.which ll accept XML string that is "<value><Root>OSLWATS</Root></value>" and it ll return string value.I mean it will return OSLWATS.

Comment: @Wojciech---THANK YOU.....IT works....:).I used <![CDATA[ and ]]> then its working...:)

Comment: one more doubt i have ,how to pass full xml string as parameter and get that xml string in result.i mean it will return <Root>mydata</Root>

Comment: `how to pass full xml string`
the same way :-)? Inside CDATA tag?
`and get that xml string in result`
I don't understand? WCF Service should have no problem with returning XML as a string.

Comment: I mean How to extract complete xml node set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401280/read-a-xml-from-a-string-and-get-some-fields-problems-reading-xml
it should help :-).

Comment: it is for parsing n I dont want parsing :(

Comment: :)) I don't understand what do you mean then. `I mean How to extract complete xml node set.` What do you mean by 'extract'?

Comment: I mean i will get the full xml in response.it will show <Root><name>OSLWATS</name></Root> in result.1st say is it possible to get this?

Comment: I don't see any problem. You could return xml as a string, but it will be wrapped inside some tags (because it is WCF specification).

Comment: I have returned xml in string.But m getting "Internal Server Error" :(

Comment: strange, so try return it surrounded in CDATA tag. If it doesn't work, then just encrypt it using BASE64, and on client's side decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

you will encrypt by base64 and pass it,on the server client you can decrypt